# Filter dvar and use in constraint

Tags: variables, filter, cplex, opl

How can I filter a dvar array by a specific criterion and store this result in a dexpr array that can be used later in a constraint? I must do this since I must evaluate certain conditions that compare the indices n and n-k where dvar [n] and dvar [n-k] are nonzero.

I'm using version 12 of Ilog Cplex Community Edition.

Answer (score 0):

Let me share a small example:

```
int n=4;
range R=1..4;

dvar int x[R];
dexpr int y[i in R]=(x[i]!=0)*i;

subject to
{
y[1]==0;
y[2]==2;
y[3]==3;
y[4]==0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean ? Can you be a little more explicit ?

Comment: the matter is as follows: Suppose that X is an integer solution vector that can take values ​​between zero and k. for my problem zero indicates that the element does not affect the objective function. For those values ​​other than zero, the solution is only feasible if x [i] -x [j] >= T but i and j are not necessarily consecutive and you never know in advance how many zero values ​​there are in the vector and their positions within the vector. I appreciate ideas about it